# Getting multiple informations from one string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this (encoded image):
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAGQCAYAAAA+89ElAAAABmJLR…AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4ApW+4QEIeKApAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

How can I get:

- the image type (`png`, **not** `image/png`);
- the hash (`iVBORw0KGgoAA…5ErkJggg==`);

I know how to use regex, but not at this level...

---

The only solution I have found is:

`data:image.([^;]+)` for type;

`[,]([\S]+)` for hash;

... but I think we can do it better?

Comment: Are you dead set on regex as explode could be a potential solution.

Comment: I have forget explode, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the string format, this is just a simple regex

```
 # '~data:image[^/]+/(\w+);\w+,([\S]+)~'
 # or
 # "~data:image[^/]+/(\\w+);\\w+,([\\S]+)~"

 data:image [^/]+ /
 ( \w+ )                # (1), type image
 ; \w+ ,                # encoding
 ( [\S]+ )              # (2), image hash
```